# Scope problems in basic Yeoman Angular Todo App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, yeoman

I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQ1fvdO9GY while learning yeoman and angular.

I've gotten to here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQ1fvdO9GY#t=266 and where his example works, mine does not due to some scope problems.

main.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>My Todos:</h2>
  <p ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
    <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
  </p>

  <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newTodoText" size="20">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add">
  </form>
</div>
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('todoAppApp');

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.todos = [
        {text: 'Item 1', done: false},
        {text: 'Item 2', done: true},
        {text: 'Item 3', done: false}
    ];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.newTodoText, done: false});
        $scope.newTodoText = '';
    };
}]);
```

For some reason, though, the `newTodoText` variable is in a scope that is child to the $scope in `main.js`. This is confirmed using Batarang. I can't post a picture due to lack of rep, but in Batarang, there's:

```
Scope001 > Scope002 > Scope003(which is the $scope I have access to in the js) > Scope004 > {Scopes for each of the todos}
```

Scope003 has the original `todos` array and the `addTodo()` function. Scope004 has the `newTodoText` text when you type into the input form. On clicking add, `addTodo()` is correctly called, but $scope doesn't contain `newTodoText` because it's in Scope004.

I'm obviously missing something simple here due to my newness to the framework and the practically barebones implementation here. My Google-fu has turned up few results.

EDIT:
Ok, so in index.html, it contains the line

```
<div class="container" ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

which includes main.html. I've replaced that line with the literal contents of main.html enclosed in the div

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!-- contents of main.html from above -->
</div>
```

And magically my scope problems are solved. Why does including main.html from a separate file mess with the scope?

EDIT #2

Cool, I figured it out.

Turns out that `ng-include` creates a new scope, which is contrary to what I thought it did (I had assumed that it was equivalent to a literal html injection). So I just moved the `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` from the .container div in index.html (Scope003) to the .jumbotron div within main.html.

Thanks for the help, and I'm a lot more knowledgeable about scope now!

Comment: Appears to work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVsLW/)- or am I missing something?

Comment: One potential source of confusion in this code is there are two `todo` variables- the input model, and the `ngRepeat` iterator.  `ngRepeat` creates it's own scope- so these two `todo` variables are on different scopes (as you note).  Personally I'd use different names for the two though, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: KayakDave: You're right that the code *should* work; it fact it does when I make a simple index.html+main.js implementation of the tutorial, but for some reason, the structure of the program itself is the origin of the scope problem.

Comment: I've fixed the scope issue by replacing the `...ng-include="'views/main.html'"...` line in index.html with the literal contents of main.html, and the scope issue is fixed. I've updated my question above. Why does including main.html from an external file mess with the scope?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` creates a new scope. So I moved the `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` from the `.container` div in `index.html` (Scope003) to the `.jumbotron` div within `main.html`.